# Data Manipulation in multiple columns(absolute, percentage, and categorical) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, machine-learning

I need to make a function, which takes input as dataframe, and dictionary{"Col_1" :% change,"Col_2":absolute change,"Col_3": 0/1(Categorical)} and it should make the changes to the dataframe.

I Have data frame like this

| Date | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 90 | 100 | 0 |
| 01/02/2022 | 80 | 110 | 1 |
| 01/03/2022 | 92 | 120 | 0 |
| 01/04/2022 | 96 | 130 | 0 |
| 01/05/2022 | 99 | 150 | 1 |
| 01/06/2022 | 105 | 155 | 1 |

Now I pass the dictionary say,

```
{"Date":["01/01/2022","01/02/2022"],"col_1":[-10,-10],"col_2":10,"col_3":[1,0]}
```

- for "col_1" I am passing -10,-10 percentage change to its previous values on specified date.
- for "col_2" I am passing an absolute number that is 10 (it should replace previous values by 10)
  specified date.
- for "col_3" I am passing a binary number and it updated in dataframe on specified date.

Then my desired out would look like this

| Date | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 81 | 10 | 1 |
| 01/02/2022 | 72 | 10 | 0 |
| 01/03/2022 | 92 | 120 | 0 |
| 01/04/2022 | 96 | 120 | 0 |
| 01/05/2022 | 99 | 150 | 1 |
| 01/06/2022 | 105 | 155 | 1 |

I followed tried this code:

```
def per_change(df,cols,d):
    df[cols] = df[cols].add(df[cols].div(100).mul(pd.Series(d)), fill_value=0)
    return df
```

but it didn't worked out. Please help!!

Comment: [tag:machine-learning] tag is superfluous

Comment: I'll keep it in mind onwards! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dic["Date"]` as a boolean mask and update values in `df` using the values under the other keys in `dic`:

```
msk = df['Date'].isin(dic['Date'])
df.loc[msk, 'col_1'] *= (1 + np.array(dic['col_1']) / 100)
df.loc[msk, 'col_2'] = dic['col_2']
df.loc[msk, 'col_3'] = dic['col_3']
```

Output:

```
         Date  col_1  col_2  col_3
0  01/01/2022   81.0     10      1
1  01/02/2022   72.0     10      0
2  01/03/2022   92.0    120      0
3  01/04/2022   96.0    130      0
4  01/05/2022   99.0    150      1
5  01/06/2022  105.0    155      1
```

Comment: Is there any way that it should pick the columns and perform the same thing as you did?

Comment: @AmitKumar what do you mean? Do you mean you don't want to do it manually for different dicts? You could wrap it in a function and just use it as you like it.

Comment: I want that columns names can also be choose automatically (not sure but using some regex())